# Select a query after try catching PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone knows why my sql query doesn't work after using a try catch function? the code is a regular code as I'm using every time and it works perfectly but when I try to use it after a try catch function it doesn't work,

```
try{
   //somecode
}
catch{
  // somecode
}
$carType = 'ECAR';
$category = substr($carType,0,1);
if($category){
    $querycy = ("SELECT * FROM carClassCodes where ClassC = '$category'");
    $resultcy = mysql_query($querycy);
    $rowcy = mysql_fetch_array($resultcy);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, now you've added code, but we don't see try/catch anywhere in it. We can't debug invisible code...

Comment: Its a very long code, the first time I'm doing this `try{}catch{}` function

Comment: Define "doesn't work" while you're at it.

Comment: Does the try{} catch{} wrap around any of the code that establishes your database connection, for example?

Comment: If the try/catch code is breaking subsequent code, we can't help you any if we don't see that code. Put yourself in your shoes - **have you provided enough information to allow someone to help you?**

Comment: Yes you're right I just add the connection after the try function, thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). It clearly shows that `catch` must be followed by what type of error to catch. In its most basic form, it's `catch(Exception $e)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add the connection after the try function, if you put the connection before the try function will it not work, so please make sure to put it afterwards.